# How do I check if textarea is HTML?

Tags: javascript, php

How do I check if what was written in the textarea by the user is valid HTML? It could be with either PHP or Javascript.

Comment: define "valid html" ?

Comment: Maybe you can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php - after load you can loaded with input using `similar_text`

Answer (score 0):

In php, it would be quite simple:

```
if($text!=htmlspecialchars($text))
{
    echo 'This contains HTML tags!!';
}
```

Of course, this means an ampersand would be valid, so you could also do something like

```
function hasHtml($string) {
    if ( $string != strip_tags($string) )
        return true;
}
```

You can use [John Resig's](http://ejohn.org/files/htmlparser.js) html parser for the Javascript solution, or do something like this:

```
function is_html(string)
{
  return string.match("/<[^<]+>/").length != 0;
}
```

Comment: Checking via htmlspecialchars would mean any string with an ampersand in it would return valid?

Comment: That's not going to tell the OP that the contents are *valid* HTML (regardless of what the OP means by valid)

Answer (score 0):

You could post the contents to a html validation script or online service and show the result.

You may also want to investigate the PHP [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class which has some validating functionality.

Answer (score 0):

in js, it's easy since it has an HTML parser built-in:

```
function isHTML(str){
  var div=document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML=str;
  return div.children.length>0;
}
```

note that this will validate that there is some well-formed html, or html that quirks into well-formed html. strict validity is another matter, and only FireFox lets you ajax view-source: urls to sniff for error title attribs in the gecko html display markup. Other browsers will need a server-side proxy to the w3 validator, or a on-site html validation service provided by your own server.